# unable to call the functions from dll injected in remote process

Tags: c++, dll-injection, remote-process

i am trying to call the function in side the dll which is injected in the Remote process, my exe code in which am trying to call the dll function is as below:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <psapi.h>
#include <string>

using std::string;


void GetDebugPrivs()
{
    HANDLE hToken;
    LUID sedebugnameValue;
    TOKEN_PRIVILEGES tp;

    if (OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), 
      TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | TOKEN_QUERY, &hToken))
    {
       if ( !LookupPrivilegeValue( NULL, SE_DEBUG_NAME, &sedebugnameValue ) )
       {
        CloseHandle( hToken );
       }

        tp.PrivilegeCount = 1;
        tp.Privileges[0].Luid = sedebugnameValue;
        tp.Privileges[0].Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;

        if ( !AdjustTokenPrivileges( hToken, 
         FALSE, &tp, sizeof(tp), NULL, NULL ) )
        {
           CloseHandle( hToken );
        }
        CloseHandle( hToken );
    }
}

HMODULE WINAPI GetRemoteModuleHandle(HANDLE hProcess, LPCSTR lpModuleName)
{
HMODULE* ModuleArray = NULL;
DWORD ModuleArraySize = 100;
DWORD NumModules = 0;
CHAR lpModuleNameCopy[MAX_PATH] = {0};
CHAR ModuleNameBuffer[MAX_PATH] = {0};

/* Make sure we didn't get a NULL pointer for the module name */
if(lpModuleName == NULL)
    goto GRMH_FAIL_JMP;

/* Convert lpModuleName to all lowercase so the comparison isn't case sensitive */
for (size_t i = 0; lpModuleName[i] != '\0'; ++i)
{
    if (lpModuleName[i] >= 'A' && lpModuleName[i] <= 'Z')
        lpModuleNameCopy[i] = lpModuleName[i] + 0x20; // 0x20 is the difference between uppercase and lowercase
    else
        lpModuleNameCopy[i] = lpModuleName[i];

    lpModuleNameCopy[i+1] = '\0';
}

/* Allocate memory to hold the module handles */
ModuleArray = new HMODULE[ModuleArraySize];

/* Check if the allocation failed */
if(ModuleArray == NULL)
    goto GRMH_FAIL_JMP;

/* Get handles to all the modules in the target process */
if(!::EnumProcessModulesEx(hProcess, ModuleArray,
    ModuleArraySize * sizeof(HMODULE), &NumModules, LIST_MODULES_ALL))
    goto GRMH_FAIL_JMP;

/* We want the number of modules not the number of bytes */
NumModules /= sizeof(HMODULE);

/* Did we allocate enough memory for all the module handles? */
if(NumModules > ModuleArraySize)
{
    delete[] ModuleArray; // Deallocate so we can try again
    ModuleArray = NULL; // Set it to NULL se we can be sure if the next try fails
    ModuleArray = new HMODULE[NumModules]; // Allocate the right amount of memory

    /* Check if the allocation failed */
    if(ModuleArray == NULL)
        goto GRMH_FAIL_JMP;

    ModuleArraySize = NumModules; // Update the size of the array

    /* Get handles to all the modules in the target process */
    if( !::EnumProcessModulesEx(hProcess, ModuleArray,
        ModuleArraySize * sizeof(HMODULE), &NumModules, LIST_MODULES_ALL) )
        goto GRMH_FAIL_JMP;

    /* We want the number of modules not the number of bytes */
    NumModules /= sizeof(HMODULE);
}

/* Iterate through all the modules and see if the names match the one we are looking for */
for(DWORD i = 0; i <= NumModules; ++i)
{
    /* Get the module's name */
    ::GetModuleBaseNameA(hProcess, ModuleArray[i],
        ModuleNameBuffer, sizeof(ModuleNameBuffer));

    /* Convert ModuleNameBuffer to all lowercase so the comparison isn't case sensitive */
    for (size_t j = 0; ModuleNameBuffer[j] != '\0'; ++j)
    {
        if (ModuleNameBuffer[j] >= 'A' && ModuleNameBuffer[j] <= 'Z')
            ModuleNameBuffer[j] += 0x20; // 0x20 is the difference between uppercase and lowercase
    }

    /* Does the name match? */
    if(strstr(ModuleNameBuffer, lpModuleNameCopy) != NULL)
    {
        /* Make a temporary variable to hold return value*/
        HMODULE TempReturn = ModuleArray[i];

        /* Give back that memory */
        delete[] ModuleArray;

        /* Success */
        return TempReturn;
    }

    /* Wrong module let's try the next... */
}


   GRMH_FAIL_JMP:

/* If we got to the point where we allocated memory we need to give it back */
if(ModuleArray != NULL)
    delete[] ModuleArray;

/* Failure... */
return NULL;
}

FARPROC WINAPI GetRemoteProcAddress (HANDLE hProcess, HMODULE hModule, LPCSTR lpProcName, UINT Ordinal, BOOL UseOrdinal)
{
BOOL Is64Bit = FALSE;
MODULEINFO RemoteModuleInfo = {0};
UINT_PTR RemoteModuleBaseVA = 0;
IMAGE_DOS_HEADER DosHeader = {0};
DWORD Signature = 0;
IMAGE_FILE_HEADER FileHeader = {0};
IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER64 OptHeader64 = {0};
IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER32 OptHeader32 = {0};
IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY ExportDirectory = {0};
IMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY ExportTable = {0};
UINT_PTR ExportFunctionTableVA = 0;
UINT_PTR ExportNameTableVA = 0;
UINT_PTR ExportOrdinalTableVA = 0;
DWORD* ExportFunctionTable = NULL;
DWORD* ExportNameTable = NULL;
WORD* ExportOrdinalTable = NULL;

/* Temporary variables not used until much later but easier
/* to define here than in all the the places they are used */
CHAR TempChar;
BOOL Done = FALSE;

/* Check to make sure we didn't get a NULL pointer for the name unless we are searching by ordinal */
if(lpProcName == NULL && !UseOrdinal)
    goto GRPA_FAIL_JMP;

/* Get the base address of the remote module along with some other info we don't need */
if(!::GetModuleInformation(hProcess, hModule,&RemoteModuleInfo, sizeof(RemoteModuleInfo)))
    goto GRPA_FAIL_JMP;
RemoteModuleBaseVA  = (UINT_PTR)RemoteModuleInfo.lpBaseOfDll;

/* Read the DOS header and check it's magic number */
if(!::ReadProcessMemory(hProcess, (LPCVOID)RemoteModuleBaseVA, &DosHeader,
    sizeof(DosHeader), NULL) || DosHeader.e_magic != IMAGE_DOS_SIGNATURE)
    goto GRPA_FAIL_JMP;

/* Read and check the NT signature */
if(!::ReadProcessMemory(hProcess, (LPCVOID)(RemoteModuleBaseVA + DosHeader.e_lfanew),
    &Signature, sizeof(Signature), NULL) || Signature != IMAGE_NT_SIGNATURE)
    goto GRPA_FAIL_JMP;

/* Read the main header */
if(!::ReadProcessMemory(hProcess,
    (LPCVOID)(RemoteModuleBaseVA + DosHeader.e_lfanew + sizeof(Signature)),
    &FileHeader, sizeof(FileHeader), NULL))
    goto GRPA_FAIL_JMP;

/* Which type of optional header is the right size? */
if(FileHeader.SizeOfOptionalHeader == sizeof(OptHeader64))
    Is64Bit = TRUE;
else if(FileHeader.SizeOfOptionalHeader == sizeof(OptHeader32))
    Is64Bit = FALSE;
else
    goto GRPA_FAIL_JMP;

if(Is64Bit)
{
    /* Read the optional header and check it's magic number */
    if(!::ReadProcessMemory(hProcess,
        (LPCVOID)(RemoteModuleBaseVA + DosHeader.e_lfanew + sizeof(Signature) + sizeof(FileHeader)),
        &OptHeader64, FileHeader.SizeOfOptionalHeader, NULL)
        || OptHeader64.Magic != IMAGE_NT_OPTIONAL_HDR64_MAGIC)
        goto GRPA_FAIL_JMP;
}
else
{
    /* Read the optional header and check it's magic number */
    if(!::ReadProcessMemory(hProcess,
        (LPCVOID)(RemoteModuleBaseVA + DosHeader.e_lfanew + sizeof(Signature) + sizeof(FileHeader)),
        &OptHeader32, FileHeader.SizeOfOptionalHeader, NULL)
        || OptHeader32.Magic != IMAGE_NT_OPTIONAL_HDR32_MAGIC)
        goto GRPA_FAIL_JMP;
}

/* Make sure the remote module has an export directory and if it does save it's relative address and size */
if(Is64Bit && OptHeader64.NumberOfRvaAndSizes >= IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_EXPORT + 1)
{
    ExportDirectory.VirtualAddress = (OptHeader64.DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_EXPORT]).VirtualAddress;
    ExportDirectory.Size = (OptHeader64.DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_EXPORT]).Size;
}
else if(OptHeader32.NumberOfRvaAndSizes >= IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_EXPORT + 1)
{
    ExportDirectory.VirtualAddress = (OptHeader32.DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_EXPORT]).VirtualAddress;
    ExportDirectory.Size = (OptHeader32.DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_EXPORT]).Size;
}
else
    goto GRPA_FAIL_JMP;

/* Read the main export table */
if(!::ReadProcessMemory(hProcess, (LPCVOID)(RemoteModuleBaseVA + ExportDirectory.VirtualAddress),
    &ExportTable, sizeof(ExportTable), NULL))
    goto GRPA_FAIL_JMP;

/* Save the absolute address of the tables so we don't need to keep adding the base address */
ExportFunctionTableVA = RemoteModuleBaseVA + ExportTable.AddressOfFunctions;
ExportNameTableVA = RemoteModuleBaseVA + ExportTable.AddressOfNames;
ExportOrdinalTableVA = RemoteModuleBaseVA + ExportTable.AddressOfNameOrdinals;

/* Allocate memory for our copy of the tables */
ExportFunctionTable = new DWORD[ExportTable.NumberOfFunctions];
ExportNameTable     = new DWORD[ExportTable.NumberOfNames];
ExportOrdinalTable  = new WORD[ExportTable.NumberOfNames];

/* Check if the allocation failed */
if(ExportFunctionTable == NULL || ExportNameTable == NULL || ExportOrdinalTable == NULL)
    goto GRPA_FAIL_JMP;

/* Get a copy of the function table */
if(!::ReadProcessMemory(hProcess, (LPCVOID)ExportFunctionTableVA,
    ExportFunctionTable, ExportTable.NumberOfFunctions * sizeof(DWORD), NULL))
    goto GRPA_FAIL_JMP;

/* Get a copy of the name table */
if(!::ReadProcessMemory(hProcess, (LPCVOID)ExportNameTableVA,
    ExportNameTable, ExportTable.NumberOfNames * sizeof(DWORD), NULL))
    goto GRPA_FAIL_JMP;

/* Get a copy of the ordinal table */
if(!::ReadProcessMemory(hProcess, (LPCVOID)ExportOrdinalTableVA,
    ExportOrdinalTable, ExportTable.NumberOfNames * sizeof(WORD), NULL))
    goto GRPA_FAIL_JMP;

/* If we are searching for an ordinal we do that now */
if(UseOrdinal)
{
    /* NOTE:
    /* Microsoft's PE/COFF specification does NOT say we need to subtract the ordinal base
    /* from our ordinal but it seems to always give the wrong function if we don't */

    /* Make sure the ordinal is valid */
    if(Ordinal < ExportTable.Base || (Ordinal - ExportTable.Base) >= ExportTable.NumberOfFunctions)
        goto GRPA_FAIL_JMP;

    UINT FunctionTableIndex = Ordinal - ExportTable.Base;

    /* Check if the function is forwarded and if so get the real address*/
    if(ExportFunctionTable[FunctionTableIndex] >= ExportDirectory.VirtualAddress &&
        ExportFunctionTable[FunctionTableIndex] <= ExportDirectory.VirtualAddress + ExportDirectory.Size)
    {
        Done = FALSE;
        string TempForwardString;
        TempForwardString.clear(); // Empty the string so we can fill it with a new name

        /* Get the forwarder string one character at a time because we don't know how long it is */
        for(UINT_PTR i = 0; !Done; ++i)
        {
            /* Get next character */
            if(!::ReadProcessMemory(hProcess,
                (LPCVOID)(RemoteModuleBaseVA + ExportFunctionTable[FunctionTableIndex] + i),
                &TempChar, sizeof(TempChar), NULL))
                goto GRPA_FAIL_JMP;

            TempForwardString.push_back(TempChar); // Add it to the string

            /* If it's NUL we are done */
            if(TempChar == (CHAR)'\0')
                Done = TRUE;
        }

        /* Find the dot that seperates the module name and the function name/ordinal */
        size_t Dot = TempForwardString.find('.');
        if(Dot == string::npos)
            goto GRPA_FAIL_JMP;

        /* Temporary variables that hold parts of the forwarder string */
        string RealModuleName, RealFunctionId;
        RealModuleName = TempForwardString.substr(0, Dot - 1);
        RealFunctionId = TempForwardString.substr(Dot + 1, string::npos);

        HMODULE RealModule = GetRemoteModuleHandle(hProcess, RealModuleName.c_str());
        FARPROC TempReturn;// Make a temporary variable to hold return value 


        /* Figure out if the function was exported by name or by ordinal */
        if(RealFunctionId.at(0) == '#') // Exported by ordinal
        {
            UINT RealOrdinal = 0;
            RealFunctionId.erase(0, 1); // Remove '#' from string

            /* My version of atoi() because I was too lazy to use the real one... */
            for(size_t i = 0; i < RealFunctionId.size(); ++i)
            {
                if(RealFunctionId[i] >= '0' && RealFunctionId[i] <= '9')
                {
                    RealOrdinal *= 10;
                    RealOrdinal += RealFunctionId[i] - '0';
                }
                else
                    break;
            }

            /* Recursively call this function to get return value */
            TempReturn = GetRemoteProcAddress(hProcess, RealModule, NULL, RealOrdinal, TRUE);
        }
        else // Exported by name
        {
            /* Recursively call this function to get return value */
            TempReturn = GetRemoteProcAddress(hProcess, RealModule, RealFunctionId.c_str(), 0, FALSE);
        }

        /* Give back that memory */
        delete[] ExportFunctionTable;
        delete[] ExportNameTable;
        delete[] ExportOrdinalTable;

        /* Success!!! */
        return TempReturn;
    }
    else // Not Forwarded
    {

        /* Make a temporary variable to hold return value*/
        FARPROC TempReturn = (FARPROC)(RemoteModuleBaseVA + ExportFunctionTable[FunctionTableIndex]);

        /* Give back that memory */
        delete[] ExportFunctionTable;
        delete[] ExportNameTable;
        delete[] ExportOrdinalTable;

        /* Success!!! */
        return TempReturn;
    }
}

/* Iterate through all the names and see if they match the one we are looking for */
for(DWORD i = 0; i<ExportTable.NumberOfNames;i++)   {
    string TempFunctionName;

    Done = FALSE;// Reset for next name
    TempFunctionName.clear(); // Empty the string so we can fill it with a new name

    /* Get the function name one character at a time because we don't know how long it is */
    for(UINT_PTR j = 0; !Done; ++j)
    {
        /* Get next character */
        if(!::ReadProcessMemory(hProcess, (LPCVOID)(RemoteModuleBaseVA + ExportNameTable[i] + j),
            &TempChar, sizeof(TempChar), NULL))
            goto GRPA_FAIL_JMP;

        TempFunctionName.push_back(TempChar); // Add it to the string

        /* If it's NUL we are done */
        if(TempChar == (CHAR)'\0')
            Done = TRUE;
    }

    /* Does the name match? */
    if(TempFunctionName.find(lpProcName) != string::npos)
    {
        /* NOTE:
        /* Microsoft's PE/COFF specification says we need to subtract the ordinal base
        /*from the value in the ordinal table but that seems to always give the wrong function */

        /* Check if the function is forwarded and if so get the real address*/
        if(ExportFunctionTable[ExportOrdinalTable[i]] >= ExportDirectory.VirtualAddress &&
            ExportFunctionTable[ExportOrdinalTable[i]] <= ExportDirectory.VirtualAddress + ExportDirectory.Size)
        {
            Done = FALSE;
            string TempForwardString;
            TempForwardString.clear(); // Empty the string so we can fill it with a new name

            /* Get the forwarder string one character at a time because we don't know how long it is */
            for(UINT_PTR j = 0; !Done; ++j)
            {
                /* Get next character */
                if(!::ReadProcessMemory(hProcess,
                    (LPCVOID)(RemoteModuleBaseVA + ExportFunctionTable[i] + j),
                    &TempChar, sizeof(TempChar), NULL))
                    goto GRPA_FAIL_JMP;

                TempForwardString.push_back(TempChar); // Add it to the string

                /* If it's NUL we are done */
                if(TempChar == (CHAR)'\0')
                    Done = TRUE;
            }

            /* Find the dot that seperates the module name and the function name/ordinal */
            size_t Dot = TempForwardString.find('.');
            if(Dot == string::npos)
                goto GRPA_FAIL_JMP;

            /* Temporary variables that hold parts of the forwarder string */
            string RealModuleName, RealFunctionId;
            RealModuleName = TempForwardString.substr(0, Dot);
            RealFunctionId = TempForwardString.substr(Dot + 1, string::npos);

            HMODULE RealModule = GetRemoteModuleHandle(hProcess, RealModuleName.c_str());
            FARPROC TempReturn;// Make a temporary variable to hold return value 


            /* Figure out if the function was exported by name or by ordinal */
            if(RealFunctionId.at(0) == '#') // Exported by ordinal
            {
                UINT RealOrdinal = 0;
                RealFunctionId.erase(0, 1); // Remove '#' from string

                /* My version of atoi() because I was to lazy to use the real one... */
                for(size_t i = 0; i < RealFunctionId.size(); ++i)
                {
                    if(RealFunctionId[i] >= '0' && RealFunctionId[i] <= '9')
                    {
                        RealOrdinal *= 10;
                        RealOrdinal += RealFunctionId[i] - '0';
                    }
                    else
                        break;
                }

                /* Recursively call this function to get return value */
                TempReturn = GetRemoteProcAddress(hProcess, RealModule, NULL, RealOrdinal, TRUE);
            }
            else // Exported by name
            {
                /* Recursively call this function to get return value */
                TempReturn = GetRemoteProcAddress(hProcess, RealModule, RealFunctionId.c_str(), 0, FALSE);
            }

            /* Give back that memory */
            delete[] ExportFunctionTable;
            delete[] ExportNameTable;
            delete[] ExportOrdinalTable;

            /* Success!!! */
            return TempReturn;
        }
        else // Not Forwarded
        {

            /* Make a temporary variable to hold return value*/
            FARPROC TempReturn;

            /* NOTE:
            /* Microsoft's PE/COFF specification says we need to subtract the ordinal base
            /*from the value in the ordinal table but that seems to always give the wrong function */
            //TempReturn = (FARPROC)(RemoteModuleBaseVA + ExportFunctionTable[ExportOrdinalTable[i] - ExportTable.Base]);

            /* So we do it this way instead */
            TempReturn = (FARPROC)(RemoteModuleBaseVA + ExportFunctionTable[ExportOrdinalTable[i]]);

            /* Give back that memory */
            delete[] ExportFunctionTable;
            delete[] ExportNameTable;
            delete[] ExportOrdinalTable;

            /* Success!!! */
            return TempReturn;
        }
    }

    /* Wrong function let's try the next... */
}


 GRPA_FAIL_JMP:

/* If we got to the point where we allocated memory we need to give it back */
if(ExportFunctionTable != NULL)
    delete[] ExportFunctionTable;
if(ExportNameTable != NULL)
    delete[] ExportNameTable;
if(ExportOrdinalTable != NULL)
    delete[] ExportOrdinalTable;

/* Falure... */
return NULL;
}

typedef void (*MYPROC)();
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
//HINSTANCE hinstLib; 
MYPROC ProcAdd;
//hinstLib = LoadLibraryA("PawIrm_Client.dll");

GetDebugPrivs();
HANDLE hproc = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, 2552);

HMODULE hwnd = GetRemoteModuleHandle(hproc, "PawIrm_Client.dll");

ProcAdd = (MYPROC)GetRemoteProcAddress(hproc, hwnd, "mypid", 0, FALSE);

if (NULL != ProcAdd) 
{
    (ProcAdd)(); // Here I am getting Unhandled exception at 0x623fb776 in PawIRM_Exe.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation.
}

CloseHandle(hproc);
return 0;
```

}

In the above exe i am trying to call the "mypid" function which is present in the dll which is injected in to the remote process, but while calling the function i am getting unhandled exception please guide me what is wrong with my code.

The Below code is My DLL:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
include  <stdlib.h>
#include "PawIrm_Client.h"

PAWIRM_CLIENT_API void mypid ()//exported function
{
DWORD PID = GetCurrentProcessId();
char arr[10] = {0};
itoa(PID, arr, 10);
MessageBoxA(NULL, arr, "PID", MB_OK);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value for ProcAdd is not a function you can call inside your current process. It's a pointer in somebody else's process. In your process, it's just a number that you're calling, and since it isn't mapped in your process, your process explodes.

Comment: Okay ...would you please tell me how to call i mean instead of ProcAdd() how can i call ...

Comment: You can't call ProcAdd from inside your own process. If you want to call it in the other process, I would suggest you call CreateRemoteThread with ProcAdd as the remote entry point. Note that ProcAdd will have to be defined to be a DWORD WINAPI ProcAdd(void* lpParam) to meet that signature requirement.

Comment: If you want to call ProcAdd in your own process, you need to load the DLL yourself in your own process and call GetProcAddress on it.

Comment: Thank you so much ..its started working after using CreateRemoteThread ...........